# I am facing he NaN error on WordPress Custom HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, nan

I am having an issue with my code when I execute the code in code editor it working good but when is execute the code in WordPress the code is not working well its giving the NaN error.

code is working fine on the w3school code editor

[image: code is working fine on w3school code editor]

when it runs the code on WordPress it gives the following error:

[image: when it is run code on WordPress is gives the following error I'm pasting the code as Custom HTML]

```js
function calculateBill() {
  const units = parseFloat(document.getElementById('units').value);
  const lessThan200 = document.getElementById('lessThan200').checked;

  // Rates
  const perUnit = 50;
  const fcSurcharge = 0.43;
  const electricityDuty = 0.20;
  const tvFee = 35;
  const gst = 2.40;
  const njSurcharge = 0.1;

  let totalBill = (perUnit + fcSurcharge + electricityDuty + gst + njSurcharge) * units + tvFee;
  if (lessThan200 && units <= 200) {
    totalBill *= 0.5; // Assuming 50% discount if less than 200 units for the last 6 months
  }

  const tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody');
  tableBody.innerHTML = `
                <tr>
                    <td>Cost of electricity (${units} x ${perUnit})</td>
                    <td>${(units * perUnit).toFixed(2)}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>F.C Surcharge</td>
                    <td>${(fcSurcharge * units).toFixed(2)}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Electricity Duty</td>
                    <td>${(electricityDuty * units).toFixed(2)}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>TV Fee</td>
                    <td>${tvFee.toFixed(2)}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>GST</td>
                    <td>${(gst * units).toFixed(2)}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>N.J Surcharge</td>
                    <td>${(njSurcharge * units).toFixed(2)}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Total Estimated Bill</th>
                    <th>${totalBill.toFixed(2)}</th>
                </tr>
            `;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.calculator {
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 450px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin: 50px auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="units">Enter Units:</label>
  <input type="number" id="units" placeholder="E.g. 200">
  <br>
  <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="lessThan200"> I am consuming 200 or less units for the last 6 months?
        </label>
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="calculateBill()">Calculate</button>

  <table>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
      <!-- Rows will be added here dynamically -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: for some reason your input is accepting the letter `e`, even tho is an input number

Comment: @ChrisG `e` is a valid letter for numbers: `1e3` equals `1,000` as `e` followed will tell how many numbers will follow which helps when working with big numbers.

Comment: Your code works. If you don't enter a value into the "Enter Units" field and then click the button to run `calculateBill()`, you'll get the 'NaN' output. Are you sure you're entering a value before calculating?

Comment: yeah but insert `e` along with any other number or just the e and you will get nothing but NaN in the results

Answer (score 0):

As @CharlieSchliesser pointed out in the comment, the error can happen if the input is empty. The easiest way to fix it is by checking if the inputted number is actually a number or NaN. You can do that by using the `isNAN(units)` function. Then simply reverse the logic with `!isNaN()` to get a true if the values is a number:

```js
function calculateBill() {
  const units = parseFloat(document.getElementById('units').value);
  if (!isNaN(units)) {
    const lessThan200 = document.getElementById('lessThan200').checked;

    // Rates
    const perUnit = 50;
    const fcSurcharge = 0.43;
    const electricityDuty = 0.20;
    const tvFee = 35;
    const gst = 2.40;
    const njSurcharge = 0.1;

    let totalBill = (perUnit + fcSurcharge + electricityDuty + gst + njSurcharge) * units + tvFee;
    if (lessThan200 && units <= 200) {
      totalBill *= 0.5; // Assuming 50% discount if less than 200 units for the last 6 months
    }

    const tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody');
    tableBody.innerHTML = `
                <tr>
                    <td>Cost of electricity (${units} x ${perUnit})</td>
                    <td>${(units * perUnit).toFixed(2)}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>F.C Surcharge</td>
                    <td>${(fcSurcharge * units).toFixed(2)}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Electricity Duty</td>
                    <td>${(electricityDuty * units).toFixed(2)}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>TV Fee</td>
                    <td>${tvFee.toFixed(2)}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>GST</td>
                    <td>${(gst * units).toFixed(2)}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>N.J Surcharge</td>
                    <td>${(njSurcharge * units).toFixed(2)}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Total Estimated Bill</th>
                    <th>${totalBill.toFixed(2)}</th>
                </tr>
            `;
  } else {
    // an error message logic should be included here
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.calculator {
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 450px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin: 50px auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="units">Enter Units:</label>
  <input type="number" id="units" placeholder="E.g. 200">
  <br>
  <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="lessThan200"> I am consuming 200 or less units for the last 6 months?
        </label>
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="calculateBill()">Calculate</button>

  <table>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
      <!-- Rows will be added here dynamically -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```